# show a panel on the html page without affect on the content

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, parent

I want to show a window (panel) on a html page every time I want by clicking a button. But I don't want it to affect on the page. For example I don't want it to change the size of page and make the page scrolled.
Actually I want to show a panel on the Google maps and add some input boxes on this panel but I cant show anything on the map.
This picture shows exactly what I want.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show what you have done so far?

Comment: Actually I want to do and I didn't start yet. But you can check this link to see what I want to do: http://upload7.ir/images/83261119921104018731.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Make the panel `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` and a child of `<body` that way the panel will overlay the current content without causing the page to grow in size.

Comment: Can you please show me an example? Whats the code to create a panel?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for you. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6XCjb/

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      .panel { 
         background: #ccc; 
         padding: 20px; 
         position: absolute;
         top: 30px;
         left: 30px;
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         z-index: 1000;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel">
    This is panel
  </div>
  <div class="map">
    <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.ru/maps?hl=ru&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=55.795502,49.073303&amp;spn=0.709453,2.113495&amp;t=m&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.ru/maps?hl=ru&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=55.795502,49.073303&amp;spn=0.709453,2.113495&amp;t=m&amp;z=10&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Просмотреть увеличенную карту</a></small>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```